# How can I improve this dynamic partial load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I am dynamically loading partials based on the occurrence drop down that is select like this:

```
<select name="scheduleevent[occurrence" id="occurrence" data-controller="remote-select" 
                        data-remote-select-url-value="<%= scheduleevents_select_path %>" 
                        data-remote-select-name-value="form[occurrence]" 
                        data-action="change->remote-select#update"  class="mb-4 w-48 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500">
                        <%= Scheduleevent.occurrences.each do |occurrence| %>
                          <option value="<%= new_scheduleevent_path(range: occurrence.second) %>"><%= occurrence.first %></option>
                        <% end %>
</select>

<%= turbo_frame_tag :ranges do %>
        <%= render partial: params[:range] ||= "0", locals: {form: form}  %>
<% end %>
```

Stimulus controller:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    url: String,
    name: String,
  }

connect() {

  }

  update() {
    const frame = document.getElementById('ranges');
    frame.src = window.event.target.value;
    
  }
}
```

This works fine to load the partial dynamically based on what value, 0, 1, etc. is passed. The only issue is that when I submit the controller the ocurrence value isn’t being saved which I need it to be. It is trying to write the URL /scheduleevents/new?range=1 into an integer field for occurrence. Is there a better way to rewrite this so I am not passing the URL through the select dropdown value so I can retain the selected value?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hard coding the URL in the stimulus controller:

```
frame.src = '/scheduleevents/new?range=' + window.event.target.value;
```